How can I achieve persistent storage for colBERT embeddings?
I am trying to develop a RAG pipeline with colBERT as embedding. I want to have a searchable, persistent storage of the knowledge base. How can I achieve that? I could see that RAGatouille framework provides an option to use FAISS for vector store. But could not find an example code for using it for later search. Could anybody please suggest?
I have tried using RAGatouille framework but could not find a way to store the embeddings in a vector store db. The ideal choice would have been pg_vector but as I understand RAGatouille doesnt support any persistent vector store other than FAISS. For that too no example code given.
